# Can you override mappings in wiremock

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock

is it possible to have a base folder of mappings and then load other folders and if they have the same file names those latter folders override the mapping in the base folder

my set up would be like

```
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0, stubs = {"classpath:/wiremock/base-mappings","classpath:/wiremock/spec-mappings"})
```

So if base mapping folder had a file serviceAresp.json
And the my specific folder also had a file serviceAresp.json.. which file would be loaded? or would they be merged?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

the last folder in the stubs part of the annotation will overwrite any files with the same name. (from what i have now tested with)